# js валидация. добавление элемента на страницу

Tags: javascript, html

Есть вот такая конструкция:

```
<form action="controller" method="post">
    <div class="block">
        <label for="one">One:</label>
        <input type="text" id="one" name="one">

  ///

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

При сабмите данные из input-a попадают в js функцию, где валидируются. Вопрос в том, что как при необходимости добавить в место, отмеченное 3мя слэшами такую строку(добавление должно происходить в функции)

```
<p>Invalid<p>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/after/

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find(".block").append("<p>Invalid</p>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="controller" method="post">
  <div class="block">
    <label for="one">One:</label>
    <input type="text" id="one" name="one">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var block = this.querySelector(".block");
  var invalid = document.createElement("p");
  invalid.textContent = "Invalid";
  block.appendChild(invalid);
});
```

```html
<form action="controller" method="post">
  <div class="block">
    <label for="one">One:</label>
    <input type="text" id="one" name="one">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: это прописать в js функции ??

Comment: мне нужен обычный js. без фрейворка

Comment: @Igor, как-то странно отслеживать клик, а не сабмит.

Comment: @MedvedevDev да, согласен